# How to delay asynchronously when a method is called consecutively?

Tags: java, delay

I want to have a delay of 1 minute before the `printFirst()` method is called without affecting the main thread.

#### Code

I tried

```java
// define delaying print-method using Timer
static void printFirst() {
  new java.util.Timer().schedule(
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println(ts() + " First");
      }
    },60000
  );
}

// main to run
System.out.println(ts() + " Zero");
printFirst();
printFirst();
printFirst();
System.out.println(ts() + " Second");
System.out.println(ts() + " Third");
System.out.println(ts() + " Fourth");
```

#### Actual Output

but the output was

```
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:40:43.664 Zero
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:40:43.666 Second
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:40:43.667 Third
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:40:43.667 Fourth
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:41:13.681 First
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:41:13.681 First
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:41:13.681 First
```

#### Expected

I was expecting an interval of 1 min between the 3 lines ending with "First".

```
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:40:43.664 Zero
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:40:43.666 Second
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:40:43.667 Third
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:40:43.667 Fourth
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:41:43.667 First
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:42:43.667 First
Timestamp: 2023-01-05 17:43:43.667 First
```

Comment: The schedule method doesn't know that the 2nd action should happen 60000 after the first action, and the 3rd should happen 60000 after that. It just knows that you want each action deferred 60000 from when it's called, and all `printFirst`s are called at the same time. You could add an integer parameter to `printFirst` and call printFirst(1), then 2, then 3. Change the delay to `60000 * myIntParam`.

Comment: I was trying to do this to create a delay between each email that is being sent @Michael

Comment: @SangminKim sorry, I somehow was confused by the separate code-blocks. Thanks for guiding me, edited to have them in one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can achieve the expected results using ExecutorService class with the newSingleThreadExecutor() method. See the code below.

```
static ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

static void printFirst() {
    es.submit(() -> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(60000);
            System.out.println(ts() + " First");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

The main method is still the same.

```
System.out.println(ts() + " Zero");
printFirst();
printFirst();
printFirst();
System.out.println(ts() + " Second");
System.out.println(ts() + " Third");
System.out.println(ts() + " Fourth");
```

When run, the results are:

```
2023-01-06 00:05:45.72 Zero
2023-01-06 00:05:45.763 Second
2023-01-06 00:05:45.763 Third
2023-01-06 00:05:45.763 Fourth
2023-01-06 00:06:45.776 First
2023-01-06 00:07:45.782 First
2023-01-06 00:08:45.784 First
```

Comment: This is great! I just do think that it lacks the es.shutdown() after the print line to free up resources

Comment: `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(60000);` Uhh, why not `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can set up your timer for periodic execution and limit the number of runs

```java
static void printFirst(long delay, int numberOfIterations) {
    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            private int counter = 0;
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(ts() + " First");

                if(++counter == numberOfIterations) {
                    this.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, delay, delay
    );
}
```

And then just run it with one command `printFirst(60000, 3);`

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue

The delay in your [`Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long initialDelay)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)) is just for the **initial** delay, time between scheduled and start of task. See parameter in docs:

> `delay` - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.

#### Solution

For your intent - as **interval** - you need the overloaded sister-method [`schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) passing the 1 minute interval as third argument to parameter named `period`:

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at **approximately regular intervals separated by the specified `period`**.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

// define the task, here in a method on demand
public static TimerTask createPrintTask(String text) {
   return new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println(ts() + text);  // not sure how ts() is defined
      }
    };
}

// define print-method using Timer with interval and zero delay
static void printScheduledWithInterval(String text, int intervalMillis) {
  var initialDelayMillis = 0; // start immediately (first after 0 seconds)
  new Timer().schedule(createPrintTask(text), initialDelayMillis, intervalMillis);
}

// MAIN
System.out.println(ts() + " Zero");

// use to start the task asynchronously (it will continue to print every interval until canceled)
printScheduledWithInterval(" First", 60_000);  // 1 minute interval

System.out.println(ts() + " Second");
System.out.println(ts() + " Third");
System.out.println(ts() + " Fourth");
```

Note: In you code there was `printFirst` called 3 times. Presumably to have 3 different tasks started or to have 3 lines printed.

#### When does the scheduling of task end?

The `printScheduledWithInterval` here, rather means schedule a print-job to be executed repeatedly on a fixed-interval.

Since there are no requirements about number of printed lines or max-execution count, the timer will continuously start new tasks.

Answer (score 0):

While calling function, you can set the number of seconds as a parameter

```
System.out.println(ts() + " Zero");
printFirst(60000);
printFirst(12000);
printFirst(18000);
System.out.println(ts() + " Second");
System.out.println(ts() + " Third");
System.out.println(ts() + " Fourth");
```

In your function,

```
static void printFirst(long time) {
  new java.util.Timer().schedule(
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println(ts() + " First");
      }
    },time
  );
}
```